# Cast / convert dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, casting, cloudkit

How can I convert an `[NSObject : AnyObject]` -> `[NSString: CKRecordValue]` in Swift?

```
personEdited!.changedValues() as [(NSString, CKRecordValue)]
```

`personEdit` in a `NSManagedObject`.

[image]

Comment: `[NSObject : AnyObject]` is not an array but a dictionary which maps `AnyObject` values to `NSObject` keys. On the other hand `[(NSString, CKRecordValue)]` is a array of a tuple. So, which type is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the key/values of the dictionary into an array containing tuples like so:

```
var dict = [ "1" : 1, "2" : 2, "3" : 3 ]
var array = Array(Zip2(dict.keys, dict.values))
```

`array` now has the type `[ (String, Int) ]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert dictionaries (`[NSObject : AnyObject]`) not array of tuples (`[(NSString, CKRecordValue)]`), try this:

```
personEdited!.changedValues() as [NSString: CKRecordValue]
```